# Performance on IndexDB vs Mongodb and website on same server?

Tags: angular, mongodb

I am a building a small scale product management web app for small business which will have just 5 users.
It will be using search bar to filter data quickly.
[image]

Front End, Backend and database all will be hosted on same pc server.

Should i use indexDB for quick queries or Should mongodb/postgresql on server PC will be enough, Since both website and mongodb/postgresql are on same PC.

Basically i don't want too much delay in data data filter and display.

Comment: It's unclear how we can begin assisting here. What is "too much delay"? What queries will you be executing? Is your hardware large enough to power both things simultaneously? How much data will the system hold?